# Issue in applying geometry grid to widgets in tkinter Notebook pages

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to apply Geometry Grid setting to the Notebook Tab widgets:

As you can see I tried this on `lb1`

> lb1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5,
>   ipady=5)

but the label still is in the middle of the tab page

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *

app = Tk()
app.configure(background='DimGray')
app.geometry('600x600')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)

note = Notebook(app)

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)

note.add(tab1, text = "Tracing", compound=TOP)
note.add(tab2, text = "Network Details")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

lb1 = Label(tab1,  text="Trace Object")
lb1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
lb1.pack()

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("Select From List")

cm = ttk.Combobox(tab1, textvariable=variable)
cm.config(values =('Select From Phase A', 'Select From Phase B'))
cm.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
cm.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

This is what I am hoping to achieve

[image]

Comment: where do you expect it to be? Also, isn't the error telling you exactly what the problem is?

Comment: at left-top of the page

Comment: I just update the post with an image of what I am hoping to get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use more than one geometry manager at the same time.

Well, I saw answers stating the same thing, but in reality you can if you do not misuse them. And this is your situation: you use more than one geometry manager but in a wrong way.

You have two options:

- Option 1:

As fir `note`, you want to use the `pack()` geometry manager for `tab1` widget. This means you have to remove away these 2 lines:

```
lb1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
```

and:

```
cm.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
```

- Option 2:

You want to use the `pack()` geometry manager for the `note` widget but you want to use `grid()` for `tab1`. You can do that safely and without confusing the Python interpreter by removing these 2 lines and keeping the former ones I mentioned above:

```
lb1.pack()
```

and:

```
cm.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks Billal , I guess I have to go with option two but when I remove the lines which you mentioned no GUI shows up after running the app. I am not either getting any error!

Comment: Really? That is strange. I can show you screenshots for the 2 options. I am running your code on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lbl.pack(side=left)
```

and

```
cm.pack(side=left)
```

that should put  both widgets to the left

Comment: Thanks H.Lunn but I am getting this error :`NameError: name 'left' is not defined` besides, what if I have  a series of widgets in next rows!?

Comment: It needs to be `"left"`, a string. As written unless you defined a variable named `left`, this code will fail.